# Service Account for Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: configuration, ms-office, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM and I want to configure MS Office applications like MS Outlook & MS Excel on it and also, chevron applications like Well Plan. To be able to do that I need a service account with MS Office license but I don't know how can I get a service account for an Azure VM. If anyone has any idea on how can I do this then please respond.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

You don’t require any service account to configure any application on azure VM.

Would suggest you  to  follow the below step to achieve your requirement in correct way.

**Step 1** : You need to first enable AAD Login into your VM.

You can refer this [MS Documen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows#enabling-azure-ad-login-in-for-windows-vm-in-azure)t to enable AAD login into your VM

ONCE configured, login with your AAD account in the VM

**Step 2**: Make Sure to give RBAC role  ([Virtual Machine Administrator Login](http://azure%20built-in%20roles%20-%20azure%20rbac%20%7C%20microsoft%20docs/) or [Virtual Machine User Login](http://azure%20built-in%20roles%20-%20azure%20rbac%20%7C%20microsoft%20docs/)) as per your requirement  for that user.

Then install office on your VM as the license is already assigned to your AAD account.

If not, you can refer this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/licensing-groups-assign) to assigned licences to User/Group.